# api\login 500 error laravel/react login

Tags: reactjs, laravel, post, authentication, fetch

Problem with authentification between `laravel/react`, when fetch get, all work:

api.php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::post('login','Auth\LoginController@login');

});

login.js

```
   getCookie(name) {
if (!document.cookie) {
  return null;
}

const xsrfCookies = document.cookie.split(';')
  .map(c => c.trim())
  .filter(c => c.startsWith(name + '='));

if (xsrfCookies.length === 0) {
  return null;
}

return decodeURIComponent(xsrfCookies[0].split('=')[1]);
  }
   const csrfToken = this.getCookie('CSRF-TOKEN');
   const headers = new Headers({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
   });

   fetch('api/login',
     {
       method: 'POST',
       headers,
       body: JSON.stringify( this.state )
     })
      .then(response=> {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({err: false});
        this.props.history.push('/') ;

      })
      .catch(error=> {
        console.log(error);
        this.refs.email.value='';
        this.refs.password.value='';
        this.setState({err: true});
      });
```

what's in console: [image: in console]
 what's  in postman: [image: in postman]

Comment: well did you look into the server logs to see whats happening?

Comment: @DZDomi yup, nothing interesting

Comment: there is 100% a log entry in the storage directory for the cause of this 500 exception; a 500 error is not coming out of nowhere

Comment: @DZDomi local.ERROR: The payload is invalid. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Encryption\\DecryptException(code: 0): The payload is invalid. at /home/vagrant/code/HW/BEPHP/diploma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:191)
[stacktrace] can u help how to resolve? oh, and when i changed to axios i had | POST http://diploma.test/api/login 419 (unknown status) and  | Error: Request failed with status code 419
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)

Comment: Is the JS in your question taken from different sections of your script as it looks like it should cause a SyntaxError?

Comment: @RossWilson just const {email , password} = this.state ;
        axios.post('api/login', {
            email,
            password,
           
          })

Comment: I was more meaning that `getCookie` looks like its part of an object and the rest of the code in not. If it's not causing an error then I guess it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A 419 error suggests that the CSRF/XSRF token has not been included correctly in the request.

The `CSRF` and `XSRF` token are not the same so that can't be used interchangeably. You can either included the CSRF as a part of the request body / a parameter or your can include the XSRF as a header.

You should be able to get your code working by changing:

```
const csrfToken = this.getCookie('CSRF-TOKEN');
const headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
});
```

to

```
const xsrfToken = this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
const headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrfToken
});
```

Comment: @Ksym Do you still get the issue when you try the above change with axios?

Comment: yes, Error: Request failed with status code 419
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)